# Upgrading CodeIgniter 1.7.2 to 2.1.4 causes Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I finally decide Upgrade my CI, I follow this user guide 
[CodeIgniter User Guide Version 2.1.4](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/upgrading.html)

but in the end when I try to load my web I get error like this

```
    Fatal error: Class 'MY_Controller' not found in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder\system\application\controllers\home.php on line 6
```

and in home.php line 6 is `class Home extends MY_Controller {`

I have file with name My_controller.php in

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myfolder\system\application\libraries
```

this is the file:

```
<?php

class  MY_Controller  extends  Controller {

  var $needLogin = FALSE;
  var $rakunpanel = FALSE;

  function __construct() {  
    parent::__construct();

    $isVisited = $this->session->userdata('visited');
    if($isVisited !== '1'){
      $this->session->set_userdata('visited', '1');
      redirect('welcome');
    }

    if($this->rakunpanel === TRUE){
      $this->needLogin = TRUE;
      $this->layout->setLayout('folderAdmin/layout_admin');
    }

    if($this->needLogin === TRUE && !$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()){
      redirect(ADMIN_PATH.'auth/login/');
    }

  }

  function is_ajax() {
    return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'));
  }  
}
```

it's hard for me cause I must follow step upgrade from CI version 1.7.2 to 2.1.4
so any suggest, why that's happen? 
thank you for all advice.

Comment: `class  MY_Controller  extends  CI_Controller {`

Comment: How are you autoloading the MY_Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** rename your `My_controller.php` to `MY_Controller.php`.

**Second:** change the parent class name to `CI_Controller`:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller { ... }
```

**And finally** put `MY_Controller.php` file inside `application/core` folder.

From the **[User Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)**:

> For example, to extend the native Input class you'll create a file
>   named `application/core/MY_Input.php`, and declare your class with:

```
class MY_Input extends CI_Input {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

new version of CI controller define: class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller